# Error when install SQL server 2008 the application was unable to start correctly (0xc0007b)

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008

"the application was unable to start correctly (0xc0007b).click ok or close button to installing application)"

Error come when i try to install SQL server 2008 in my system.

How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Error 0xc0007b means ERROR_INVALID_NAME:

```
C:\Windows\system32>err 0xc0007b
# anonymous HRESULT: Severity: SUCCESS (0), Facility 0xc0, Code 0x7b
# for hex 0x7b / decimal 123
  INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE                                       bugcodes.h
# Check for viruses on your computer. Remove any newly
# installed
# hard drives or hard drive controllers. Check your hard
# drive
# to make sure it is properly configured and terminated.
# Run CHKDSK /F to check for hard drive corruption, and then
# restart your computer.
  ScopeAllow_AddFilter_value                                     dhcpsmsg.h
  NMERR_SECURITY_BREACH_CAPTURE_DELETED                          netmon.h
  ERROR_INVALID_NAME                                             winerror.h
# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is
# incorrect.
  SQL_123_severity_15                                            sql_err
# Batch/procedure exceeds maximum length of %d characters.
# 5 matches found for "0xc0007b"
```

You should run `chkdsk /R /F` to detect and repair NTFS issues.